# Graph of Laplace equation

Tags: differential-equations

I have solved the following Laplace equation

```
a0 = (1/Pi) Integrate[Cos[φ]^2 + Sin[φ]^3, {φ, 0, 2 Pi}]
an = (1/Pi) Integrate[(Cos[φ]^2 + Sin[φ]^3)*Cos[n*φ], {φ, 0, 2 Pi}]
Plot[an, {n, 0, 10}]
bn = (1/Pi) Integrate[(Cos[φ]^2 + Sin[φ]^3)*Sin[n*φ], {φ, 0, 2 Pi}]
ann = an*Cos[n*φ]
bnn = bn*Sin[n*φ]
a = Sum[((r/4)^n)*(ann + bnn), {n, 1, Infinity}]
f[r_, φ_] := a0/2 + a
ParametricPlot3D[{r,φ, f[r, φ]}, {r, 0, 1}, {φ, 0, 2 Pi}]
Plot3D[f[r, φ], {r, 0, 1}, {φ, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

My problem is that Plot3D and ParametricPlot3D doesn't work. Any help?

Comment: `a` is still expressed as a sum; a value cannot be calculated even if I plug in numbers for `r` and `phi`. This is not a plotting problem (yet). You will have to find a way to calculate the value of your sum first.

Comment: I can't understand your answer, I am confused, please solve my question

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

a[0] = (1/Pi) Integrate[
   Cos[φ]^2 + Sin[φ]^3, {φ, 0, 2 Pi}]

(* 1 *)

a[2] = (1/Pi) Integrate[(Cos[φ]^2 + Sin[φ]^3)*
    Cos[2*φ], {φ, 0, 2 Pi}]

(* 1/2 *)

a[n_Integer] = Assuming[Element[n, Integers],
  (1/Pi) Integrate[(Cos[φ]^2 + Sin[φ]^3)*
     Cos[n*φ], {φ, 0, 2 Pi}]]

(* 0 *)

a[n_] =
 (1/Pi) Integrate[(Cos[φ]^2 + Sin[φ]^3)*
    Cos[n*φ], {φ, 0, 2 Pi}]

(* ((12 Sin[n π]^2)/(9 - 10 n^2 + n^4) + ((-2 + n^2) Sin[2 n π])/(
 n (-4 + n^2)))/π *)

Plot[a[n], {n, 0, 4.2},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[{#, a[#]} & /@ Range[0, 4]]}]
```

[image]

```
b[1] = (1/Pi) Integrate[(Cos[φ]^2 + Sin[φ]^3)*
    Sin[φ], {φ, 0, 2 Pi}]

(* 3/4 *)

b[3] = (1/Pi) Integrate[(Cos[φ]^2 + Sin[φ]^3)*
    Sin[3 φ], {φ, 0, 2 Pi}]

(* -(1/4) *)

b[n_Integer] =
 Assuming[Element[n, Integers],
  (1/Pi) Integrate[(Cos[φ]^2 + Sin[φ]^3)*
     Sin[n*φ], {φ, 0, 2 Pi}]]

(* 0 *)

b[n_] = 
 (1/Pi) Integrate[(Cos[φ]^2 + Sin[φ]^3)*Sin[n*φ],
   {φ, 0, 2 Pi}]

(* ((2 (-2 + n^2) Sin[n π]^2)/(n (-4 + n^2)) - (6 Sin[2 n π])/(
 9 - 10 n^2 + n^4))/π *)

Plot[b[n], {n, 0, 5.5},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[{#, b[#]} & /@ Range[0, 5]]}]
```

[image]

```
an[n_] := a[n]*Cos[n*φ];

bn[n_] := b[n]*Sin[n*φ];

sum = Sum[((r/4)^n)*(an[n] + bn[n]), {n, 1, 10}]

(* 1/32 r^2 Cos[2 φ] + 3/16 r Sin[φ] - 1/256 r^3 Sin[3 φ] *)
```

where the sum was truncated since the higher terms are zero.

```
f[r_, φ_] = a[0]/2 + sum;

Minimize[{f[r, φ], 0 <= r <= 1, 
  0 <= φ <= 2 Pi}, {r, φ}]

(* {71/256, {r -> 1, φ -> (3 π)/2}} *)

Maximize[{f[r, φ], 0 <= r <= 1, 
  0 <= φ <= 2 Pi}, {r, φ}]

(* {169/256, {r -> 1, φ -> π/2}} *)

ParametricPlot3D[{r, φ, f[r, φ]},
 {r, 0, 1}, {φ, 0, 2 Pi},
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {1/4, 2/3}},
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/2},
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {r, φ, f})]
```

[image]

The same plot with

```
Plot3D[f[r, φ], {r, 0, 1}, {φ, 0, 2 Pi},
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {1/4, 2/3}},
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/2},
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {r, φ, f})]
```

Comment: Very nice observation about the integer values. Especially nice to learn that high ranking terms cancel (i.e., sum to zero) in the Infinite sum. Well done!

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
f[r_, φ_] := a0/2 + a
```

By

```
f[r_, φ_] = a0/2 + a
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or leave your definition and use Evaluate. Read up on Hold and the plotting commands. Also Definition[f] is very useful.

```
ParametricPlot3D[{r, \[CurlyPhi], Evaluate[f[r, \[CurlyPhi]]]}, {r, 0,
   1}, {\[CurlyPhi], 0, 2 Pi}]
```